Keyboard shortcuts for running last command with changes?
I frequently run sequences of administrative commands interactively in Bash. I read the responses before continuing but these chains can take several goes before I'm satisfied. These sorts of chains often involve a single system with multiple sub-commands, or "actions":
sudo apt depends package
sudo apt rdepends package
sudo apt purge package
sudo apt install package

systemctl --user status whatever.service
systemctl --user restart whatever.service

The "action", the thing you're actually doing is buried in the middle of the command. After almost two decades of this, it still takes me four steps to go from one command to the next:

↑ to show the previous command
Ctrl+← until the carat is in the right place
Alt+Backspace to remove a word
Type the new "action", and Return.

What I'm asking for might seem lazy, but I've actually run into this a few times this morning on much longer commands, where it's taken a good few seconds to hunt through the line to replace the action. What I want to know is: is this really as good as it gets?
I'm regularly astounded by how much I don't know, so I'd not be too shocked to learn there's a quick-inline-word-replace shortcut that I've never heard of before.

In bash, you can use quick substitution with ^...^...:

^string1^string2^
Quick Substitution. Repeat the last command, replacing string1 with
string2. Equivalent to !!:s^string1^string2^.

The trailing ^ can be omitted. Example:
bash-5.2$ echo foo bar foo
foo bar foo
bash-5.2$ ^foo^baz
echo baz bar foo
baz bar foo

So:
sudo apt depends package
^dep^rdep
^rdepends^purge
^purge^install


The only way that could be any better would be tab completion.

Muru's method is definetly simpler, and has the advantage of not forcing the user to give up on Emacs-style keybindings.
However for those used to Vi motions, with Bash set in Vi mode (set -o vi), to replace the second-to-last word (e.g. "depends" in sudo apt depends package) one could:

Hit ↑
Hit ESC
Type 2BcW (case sensitive)

One may change 2 to 3 (3BcW) to address the third-to-last word and so on.
2BcW basically means: go Back at the start of the current whitespace-separated word (or at the start of the previous whitespace-separated word if already at the start of a whitespace-separated word) 2 times and change a whitespace-separated Word.
This will always remove the second-to-last whitespace-separated word, leaving the cursor between the whitespace that separates it from the last word and the third-to-last word. An advantage to this is you don't have to specify the word to replace.
For those used to Vi motions, this would be second nature. I wouldn't recommend setting up Bash for use with this method to users that need to be fast and are not yet used to Vi motions as again, setting Bash to Vi mode would force them to give up on Emacs-style keybindings.

Sometimes it's easier to count starting from the start of the command; e.g. to replace the third word (e.g. "depends" in sudo apt depends package) one could:

Hit ↑
Hit ESC
Type 02WcW (case sensitive)

One may change 2 to 3 (03WcW) to address the fourth word and so on.
